# How to pass a php variable from a dropdown to another dropdown using php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, database, drop-down-menu

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Student Scheduling System</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">

                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="student.php"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Student</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="coourses.php"><i class="fa fa-university fa-fw"></i> Courses</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="subject.php"><i class="fa fa-archive fa-fw"></i> Subjects</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h3 class="page-header">Student</h3>
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Student List
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table  class="table table-striped table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Student ID</th>
                                            <th>First Name</th>
                                            <th>Last Name</th>
                                            <th>Course</th>
                                            <th>Year</th>
                                            <th>Section</th>
                                            <th>Section ID</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>


                         <?php
                            // Five steps to PHP database connections:

                            // 1. Create a database connection
                            //      (Use your own servername, username and password if they are different.)
                            //      $connection allows us to keep refering to this connection after it is established
                            $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
                            if (!$connection) {
                                die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                            // 2. Select a database to use 
                            $db_select = mysql_select_db("studsystem",$connection);
                            if (!$db_select) {
                                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                        ?>

                        <?php
                        $result = mysql_query("Select tbl_course.studno, tbl_course.studfname, tbl_course.studlname, 
                            tbl_coursetype.course_desc, tblyear.YearName, tblset.setname, tblset.ID
                            from tbl_course, tbl_coursetype, tblyear, tblset 
                            where tbl_coursetype.course_no=tbl_course.studcourse 
                            AND tblyear.ID=tbl_course.studyear 
                            AND tblset.ID=tbl_course.studset", $connection);

                            if (!$result) {
                                die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                            // 4. Use returned data
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo "<tr class=\"success\">";
                                            echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row[5]."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row[6]."</td>";
                                            echo "<td><a href=\"viewsubject.php?cours={$row[3]}&year={$row[4]}&set={$row[5]}&section={$row[6]}\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-xs\">View Subject</a></td>";
                                            echo "<td><a href=\"update_stud.php?studno={$row[0]}&studfname={$row[1]}&studlname={$row[2]}&studcourse={$row[3]}\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"></i></a></td>";
                                            echo "<td><a href=\"delete_stud.php?studno={$row[0]}\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i></a></td>";
                                        echo "</tr>";

                            }

                            ?>

                            <?php
                            mysql_close($connection);
                            ?>


                                     </tbody>
                                </table>


                            </div>
                            <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->

                    </div>

                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Add Student
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new student</h4>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form role="form" action="save_stud.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="studfname" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="studlname" class="form-control" required>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Student Course</label> 
            <select name="studcourse" class="form-control">
                      <?php

                            // Five steps to PHP database connections:

                            // 1. Create a database connection
                            //      (Use your own servername, username and password if they are different.)
                            //      $connection allows us to keep refering to this connection after it is established
                            $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
                            if (!$connection) {
                                die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                            // 2. Select a database to use 
                            $db_select = mysql_select_db("studsystem",$connection);
                            if (!$db_select) {
                                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                        ?>

                <?php
                    $result = mysql_query("Select setcours, course_desc 
                        from tblset, tbl_coursetype 
                        where tbl_coursetype.course_no=tblset.setcours 
                        group by setcours", $connection);

                        if (!$result) {
                        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                        }


                      // 4. Use returned data
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                                echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  

                            }

                ?>

            </select> 
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Student Year</label> 
            <select name="studyear" class="form-control">

                      <?php
                            // Five steps to PHP database connections:

                            // 1. Create a database connection
                            //      (Use your own servername, username and password if they are different.)
                            //      $connection allows us to keep refering to this connection after it is established
                            $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
                            if (!$connection) {
                                die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                            // 2. Select a database to use 
                            $db_select = mysql_select_db("studsystem",$connection);
                            if (!$db_select) {
                                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                        ?>

                    <?php
                    $result = mysql_query("Select setyear, YearName 
                        from tblset, tblyear
                        where tblyear.ID=tblset.setyear 
                        group by setyear", $connection);

                        if (!$result) {
                        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                    }
                      // 4. Use returned data
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                                echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  

                            }

                ?>


            </select> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Section</label> 
            <select name="studset" class="form-control">

                      <?php
                            // Five steps to PHP database connections:

                            // 1. Create a database connection
                            //      (Use your own servername, username and password if they are different.)
                            //      $connection allows us to keep refering to this connection after it is established
                            $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
                            if (!$connection) {
                                die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                            // 2. Select a database to use 
                            $db_select = mysql_select_db("studsystem",$connection);
                            if (!$db_select) {
                                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                            }

                        ?>

                <?php
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblset t LIMIT 0,1000", $connection);
                        if (!$result) {
                        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                    }

                      // 4. Use returned data
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                                echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  

                            }

                ?>


            </select> 
            </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" class="form-control">
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Modal-->
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->


</body>
```

-Above is the whole code. And below are the screenshots.
[image: This is my first dropdown which is the course of the student]
[image: And this is my second dropdown which is the year levels of each course]

I am confused because BSIT has only 1st year level but when everytime I choose BSIT, the second dropdown will also appear 3rd year level, which is 3rd year is only intended for BSED. In short, I want that when everytime I choose a course, it will automatically change the second dropdown menu with its corresponding year level/s. I am sorry for this, but I just want to know if it is possible and how? Please teach me if it is okay with you. Thanks!

Comment: u want to change the value of one dropdown based on the selected value of another dropdown?? if so use ajax for that.

Comment: this is easier to achieve with frontend-scripting (javascript). with jQuery for example you can write easy event handlers, for example:`$("select.course").on("change", function(){ if($(this).val() == 1){ $("select.year").val(1) } else if($(this).val() == 2){$("select.year").val(5)}});`

Comment: Yes. But sadly, I don't know how, even to use AJAX. We are not thought on how to use ajax. Can you please teach me if it is okay? But if you wont its okay. @NiranjanNRaju

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju why would you need ajax for that?

Comment: if he wants multiple values to come in second select box??

Comment: Where will I be putting that code @low_rents?

Comment: take a look at [ChainedJs](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained)

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju and? he will need javascript/jquery - but why would he need ajax? you can for example preload multiple selectboxes with multiple values and toggle their visibility with javascript. its even better and faster because you don't need to access the server for every select change-event.

Comment: if values are more, you to store the values on load?? we can call ajax when required and populate the select box.

Comment: @RoyalRyt the code has to fit to the classes used in your html code. but you would place it somewhere in the html code, wrapped into `script` tags and into jquery's `document ready` function.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju but this user apparently doesn't know anything about ajax - and in this case he doesn't need it. it's much more simple for him to do it without ajax. plus ajax produces a lot of unneeded traffic. just preload all the data once - you can even store it into objects - and load it on the client-side when needed. it's faster and produces less request-traffic.

Comment: `<div class="form-group">
            <label>Student Course</label> 
            <select name="studcourse" class="form-control">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    $("select.studcourse").on("change", function(){ if($(this).val() == 1){ $("select.studyear").val(1) } else if($(this).val() == 2){$("select.studyear").val(5)}});
                }
});
                </script>` I placed it inside the class _studcourse_ @low_rents

Comment: How to put the selected item from database inside `<option value='item_from_database'>`? Is it possible to do this way, `<option value='$result'>`? @LuthandoLoot

Comment: Was it correct? Hehehe I am sorry for asking too much question. I didn't really get it for now. @low_rents

Comment: @RoyalRyt you mean this `echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</option>";`

Comment: Yes. Is it possible? @LuthandoLoot

Comment: Can you give me an example using my code if it is okay? It is not working, however I think, I just missed any code or something. Using php with mysql database. @LuthandoLoot

Comment: your code is very long, my answer works fine with php, all you have to do is make sure that the 2nd select option's classname is equal to the value of the 1st select box option. also make sure you are using the right `id`'s on your selectors `$('#select1').on("change", function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I suggested in the comments, you can use [chainedjs](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) for this, or you can create your own function like:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#select1').on("change", function(){
      var selectedClass = $(this).val(); //store the selected value
      $('#select2').val("");             //clear the second dropdown selected value

      //now loop through the 2nd dropdown, hide the unwanted options
      $('#select2 option').each(function () {
        var newValue = $(this).attr('class');
        if (selectedClass != newValue && selectedClass != "") {
            $(this).hide();  
        }
      else{$(this).show(); }
     });
    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="number1">number 1</option>
  <option value="number2">number 2</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option class=""></option>
  <option class="number1">number 1.1</option>
  <option class="number2">number 2.1</option>
  <option class="number1">number 1.2</option>
  <option class="number2">number 2.3</option>
  <option class="number1">number 1.3</option>
  <option class="number1">number 1.2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example using my code if it is okay? It is not working, however I think, I just missed any code or something.

Comment: Using `php` with mysql database.