# How to chain dropdown boxes using PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, chain

This is my db:

```
          [tblset]              |     [tblyear]    |    [tbl_coursetype]
ID, setname, setyear, setcours  |   ID, YearName   | course_no, course_desc   
------------------------------  | ---------------- | -----------------------
1      A        1         1     |   1   1st Year   |     1          BSIT
2      B        3         2     |   2   2nd Year   |     2          BSED
                                |   3   3rd Year   |
                                |   4   4th Year   |
                                |   5   5th Year   |
```

- And this is my code:

  ```
      <form role="form" action="save_stud.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="studfname" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="studlname" class="form-control" required>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
          <label>Student Course</label> 
          <select name="studcourse" class="form-control">
                    <?php

                          // Five steps to PHP database connections:

                          // 1. Create a database connection
                          //      (Use your own servername, username and password if they are different.)
                          //      $connection allows us to keep refering to this connection after it is established
                          $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
                          if (!$connection) {
                              die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                          }

                          // 2. Select a database to use 
                          $db_select = mysql_select_db("studsystem",$connection);
                          if (!$db_select) {
                              die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                          }

                      ?>

              <?php
                  $result = mysql_query("Select setcours, course_desc 
                      from tblset, tbl_coursetype 
                      where tbl_coursetype.course_no=tblset.setcours 
                      group by setcours", $connection);

                      if (!$result) {
                      die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                      }


                    // 4. Use returned data
                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                              echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  

                          }

              ?>

          </select> 
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
          <label>Student Year</label> 
          <select name="studyear" class="form-control">

                    <?php
                          // Five steps to PHP database connections:

                          // 1. Create a database connection
                          //      (Use your own servername, username and password if they are different.)
                          //      $connection allows us to keep refering to this connection after it is established
                          $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
                          if (!$connection) {
                              die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                          }

                          // 2. Select a database to use 
                          $db_select = mysql_select_db("studsystem",$connection);
                          if (!$db_select) {
                              die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                          }

                      ?>

                  <?php
                  $result = mysql_query("Select setyear, YearName 
                      from tblset, tblyear
                      where tblyear.ID=tblset.setyear 
                      group by setyear", $connection);

                      if (!$result) {
                      die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                  }
                    // 4. Use returned data
                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                              echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  

                          }

              ?>


          </select> 
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <label>Section</label> 
          <select name="studset" class="form-control">

                    <?php
                          // Five steps to PHP database connections:

                          // 1. Create a database connection
                          //      (Use your own servername, username and password if they are different.)
                          //      $connection allows us to keep refering to this connection after it is established
                          $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
                          if (!$connection) {
                              die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                          }

                          // 2. Select a database to use 
                          $db_select = mysql_select_db("studsystem",$connection);
                          if (!$db_select) {
                              die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
                          }

                      ?>

              <?php
                  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblset t LIMIT 0,1000", $connection);
                      if (!$result) {
                      die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                  }

                    // 4. Use returned data
                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                              echo "<option value=\"{$row[0]}\">{$row[1]}</option>";  

                          }

              ?>


          </select> 
          </div>
  ```

-Here are some screenshots. 
[image: Choosing course]
[image: Choosing year level]

Now, I am confused because `BSIT` has only `1st year` but when everytime I choose `BSIT`, the second dropdown will also appear `3rd year`, which infact, `3rd year` is only intended for `BSED`.

In short, I want that when everytime I choose a course, it will automatically change the second dropdown menu with its corresponding year level/s.

I am new at php and mysql, and I don't know how to fix this issue. I've been trying to search any code over the internet for almost 1 week but no one's working, maybe I don't know how so I can't trace why it does so.

Can someone help me? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday?

Comment: You need to use AJAX for that. Look into [jQuery Ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method. You need to bind the ajax call that queries db for second dropdown contents to the first dropdown `onChange()` event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a php variable from a dropdown to another dropdown using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079923/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-from-a-dropdown-to-another-dropdown-using-php)

Comment: your last question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079923/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-from-a-dropdown-to-another-dropdown-using-php

Comment: as i said yesterday also, use ajax for this,

Comment: @Qirel Sorry for this. But I posted this again trying to seek for an answer to solve this issue. I did try the codes given yesterday but its not working maybe because, just like I say, I am new at php and mysql, even ajax.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Sorry for this. But I posted this again trying to seek for an answer to solve this issue. I did try the codes given yesterday but its not working maybe because, just like I say, I am new at php and mysql, even ajax.

Comment: If the answer you accepted for this question yesterday is not working for you... why is it the accepted answer?

Comment: @RoyalRyt Posting a question twice isn't really going to help you. Take a look at [w3schools'](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) example. If you can't figure it out from there, then you probably should learn basic PHP and MySQL first.

Comment: I will. Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for asking this twice. @Qirel

Comment: so based on course, you want to fetch year??

Comment: Hi @RoyalRyt. You Got Answer?

Comment: I don't have yet sir. @NanaPartykar

Comment: Do yourself a favor - **stop using mysql_**. `mysql_` has been [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Using `mysql_` leaves you wide open to [sql injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Soon your code will stop functioning completely and you'll be back asking a [question like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/). Skip `mysqli_` and go straight to learning [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). When your host upgrades to PHP 7, you will be so happy you did. Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into AJAX (asynchronous JavaScript and XML). It will help you solve the *automatically change the second dropdown menu with its corresponding year level/s* problem you have.

AJAX is a group of Web development techniques used on the client side to create asynchronous Web applications. In short you will be able send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously, in other words you can only reload (and therefore change the content of) one (or more) dropdowns based on a previous user input (without reloading the whole page). Which, as far as I understand, is what you want.

Otherwise you can also implement this without using AJAX, but it will require the whole page to reload.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript to change the contents of the page after the DOM has loaded. You *could* refresh the page whenever the select has changed, but if I were you, i'd either

1. Load the combinations into a JS object
2. Use ajax to fetch them asynchronously.

Your case is fairly simple, so in my humble opinion, the latter would cause a pretty unnecessary request overhead; if you don't have 50+ courses with a lot of year combinations, I would approach it in the first way. Here is a **VERY** simple version of what I'm talking about, using jQuery for simplicity: http://jsfiddle.net/eng2e9fu/

```
var courses = {
    1:{years:2},
    2:{ years:3},
    };

$("#course").change(function(){
    var course = $(this).val();
    var options = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= courses[course].years; i++)
    {
        options.push($("<option/>").attr("value",i).html("Year "+i));
    }

    $("#year").html(options);
});
```

Comment: How to do these using MYSQL Query?

Comment: You wanna focus on generating the `courses` object. You're asking a lot of things here, and you won't get a ready-to-copy-paste-answer here at stackoverflow. The hint is: in the above case, try focusing on generating the "courses" object. The general idea is to manipulate your data into a PHP array and then use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to get it output to valid JSON (which javascript understands). `var courses = <?=json_encode($array)?>;`

Answer (score 0):

First take a backup of your code. And, use my code. I'm 100% sure, it will work. But, keep patient. And, use this code in very calm manner. Understand each and every line.

**dbconnect.php** 
(include this file in each and every page where Database Connection is needed. Why to write each time code for Database Connection)

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db("studsystem",$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

**Your Modal Page**

```
<?include('dbconnect.php');?>
.
//Your rest of the code
.
<form role="form" action="save_stud.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="studfname" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="studlname" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Student Course</label> 
        <select name="studcourse" class="form-control Courses">
            <option value="">Select Courses</option>
            <?
                $QueryCourses = mysql_query("SELECT tblset.setcours, tbl_coursetype.course_desc 
                FROM tblset, tbl_coursetype WHERE tbl_coursetype.course_no=tblset.setcours", $connection);
                while ($RowCourses = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {?>
                <option value="<?echo $RowCourses[0];?>"><?echo $RowCourses[1];?></option>
                <?}?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group StudentYearDiv">
        <label>Student Year</label> 
        <select name="studyear" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Year</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Section</label> 
        <select name="studset" class="form-control">
            <option value="Select Section"></option>
            <?
            $QuerySection=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblset LIMIT 0,1000", $connection);
            while($RowQS=mysql_fetch_array($QuerySection))
            {?>
                <option value="<?echo $RowQS[0];?>"><?echo $RowQS[1];?></option>
            <?}?>
        </select>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    //Your rest of the code
</form>
```

Add this code either in your footer.
If, after adding it didn't worked, then keep this  code in your modal page only.

```
<script>
    $('.Courses').change(function(){
        var CourseNo=$('.Courses').val();
        $.ajax({url:"Ajax-ShowStudentYear.php?CourseNo="+CourseNo,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $('.StudentYearDiv').html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

Create one **Ajax-ShowStudentYear.php** page.
(Remember, if you want to change this page name. Then, change in your `<script></script>` tag too. Both are related)

```
<?
include('dbconnect.php');
extract($_GET);

$QueryYearNo=mysql_query("SELECT setyear FROM tblset WHERE setcours='$CourseNo'",$connection);
while($RowYN=mysql_fetch_array($QueryYearNo))
{
    $YearNo=$RowYN['setyear'];
}
?>

<label>Student Year</label> 
<select name="studyear" class="form-control">
    <?
    $QueryYear=mysql_query("SELECT ID, YearName FROM tblyear WHERE ID='$YearNo'",$connection);
    while($RowQY=mysql_fetch_array($QueryYear))
    {?>
        <option value="<?echo $RowQY['ID'];?>"><?echo $RowQY['YearName'];?></option>
    <?}?>
</select>
```

Cheers! Enjoy Coding :) :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me sir. I think this will really work but one thing, is there any glitch over the `$QueryCourses` query? I got nothing on the first dropdown box.

Comment: Hi @RoyalRyt. I didn't changed your query. But, what i observed is your query was wrong. Since 2 columns of different tables you were fetching.. you have to use my way. I've edited my answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the database structure you provided in your question, you can achieve the result by using AJAX.

1. Start by querying to get your courses...

   prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll();
    $totalRows = $query->rowCount();
    ?>
2. Include the function in your `<head>` tags

   function getYears(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get-year.php",
        data:'id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#year-list").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
3. The form

   Student Course
    
    Select Course
    
    ">
    
    
    
    
    Student Year
    
    Select Year
4. The sql to pull available years... get-year.php

   prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        $results = $query->fetchAll();
        $totalRows = $query->rowCount();
    ?>

   ```
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
   ```

   ```
    <option value="<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["YearName"]; ?></option>
   ```

Of course you can change your connection include line to match what you use & `$conn->` to whatever you currently use.